# Apache+PHP - Browse all stored sessions, choose nad delete some

Tags: php, apache, session, debian, session-variables

Is there a way, how to browse through stored sessions and delete some? I am aware there may not be a native PHP access for it, but it should be stored in files somewhere, right?

PHP 5.4.41

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Debian 7.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_save_path()` returns the path of the directory used to save session data. You can then visit this folder and delete what you need.